# MySql - Query How to write nested condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name : allocate_rooms
has id, room_id, startTime, endTime.

now I have to find the Query where result should be return zero 
Means user will give input as room id and startTime and endTime and it should check whether in that room_id there is any startTime and endTime

Eg: if someone give room name as sunday and startTime as 12:00:00 and endTime as 12:30:00 it will check whether in sunday there is any startTime and endTime
But if he give room name as Monday user can save the input.

```
SELECT id FROM allocate_rooms
         where startTime='12:00:00' and endTime=' 12:30:00' AND day_id = 'sunday'
```

I have written the Query but it's not working properly. How do I write the exact query?

Comment: What are the data types for the `startTime` and `endTime` fields? `DATE` or `DATETIME`? Also, your query is referencing `start` and `end` and not `startTime` and `endTime` as you've specified.

Comment: what is problem with your query? whats the expected output ?

Comment: @KP. the above Query should return zero if it whether the in that day day_id whether there is any startTime or endTime or 1 if it matches with the day_id but don't have startTime and endTime with that day_id in that database.

Comment: @sbeliv01 yup both are  `Time ` type only

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need `0` or `1` as output, try the below query

```
SELECT ifnull (id, 0, 1)
FROM allocate_rooms
WHERE startTime='12:00:00' or endTime=' 12:30:00'
     AND day_id = 'sunday'
```

Comment: But day_id should be varies means in that day user can save other time if it doesn't match with the database of startTime and endTime

Comment: You should post what's your input data and expected output

Comment: See I need to check the startTime and endTime which should have match with day_id otherwise condition failed. and if day_id matched but the startTime and endTime doesn't then also condition false.